# Storing different classes within one Dictionary, allow execution

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two classes:

```
public class Variable<T>;
public class Closure;
```

Both share these properties:

```
public string handle;
public string description;
```

Both have method named `GetValue`:

```
public T GetValue(); // Variable<T>
public string GetValue(params string[] arguments); // Closure
```

`Variable<T>` has an extra method `SetValue`:

```
public string SetValue(object newValue);
```

---

These classes represent a Video Games, Console components property.

What I want to do is, keep both of these within one `Directory`, yet allow to easily access / manipulate public properties, methods of classes.

I did try adding a dummy `interface`, but that lost the relation to object, returning interface instance, therefore preventing me to use those public properties, methods:

```
public static class Storage
{
    public static Dictionary<string, IConsoleProperty> Variables = new Dictionary<string, IConsoleProperty>();

    public static string Inform()
    {
        string output = "";

        foreach (var variable in Variables)
        {
            output += string.Format("{0} : {1}", variable.Key, variable.Value.description);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

> Type `Console.IConsoleProperty` does not contain a definition for `description` and no extension method `description' of type`Console.IConsoleProperty` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I read that I should cast in such scenario, but I'm clueless how to dynamically cast from string (`typeof(variable.Value)`) especially with `Generic` instances of multiple types.

How to keep both of these classes within one Directory, yet upon value retrieval, get base class instance instead of interface?

Comment: What does IConsoleProperty look like?  Sounds like it doesn't have neither `handle` nor `description` on it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, these:

```
public string handle;
public string description;
```

are not public properties, they are public fields. Public properties are done like so:

```
public string Handle { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Do think about if you really need to change these from outside the class, though.

To answer your question, though, your two classes share some characteristics, but they are quite different. So the cleanest solution would actually be to have two dictionaries. Do not try to make two things the same which the really aren't.

You can access an objects type information by calling the `GetType()` method on it. You can check if it is of type `T` by doing

```
if (myObj is T)
```

But there is no way to cast something down to "whatever it really is".

Comment: +1. Note that you can emulate "whatever it really is" with `dynamic`... But having separate collections for unrelated object would be easier. If the objects are related than creating/implementing common interface is a good approach.

Comment: I could go with the two Dictionary solution, but in such case, how'd I store the Generic Variable items - interface again?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to include `handle` and `description` in your `IConsoleProperty` interface.  This way 
`variable.Value` will return an `IConsoleProperty` which contains `handle` and `description`.  Then you'll be able to use `handle` and `description`.  However, you'll have to cast if you want to use the non shared public members.

```
public interface IConsoleProperty 
{
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Variable<T> : IConsoleProperty
{
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    //Rest of Variable class
}
public class Closure : IConsoleProperty
{
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    //Rest of Closure class
}
```

If you need to do some casts you can do something like:

```
if (variable.Value is Closure)
{
    var myClosure = (Closure)variable.Value;
    //Do stuff with myClosure
}
//Susbstitute MyOtherClass with the appropriate type argument
if (variable.Value is Variable<MyOtherClass>) 
{
    var myVariable = (Variable<MyOtherClass>)variable.Value;
    //Do stuff with myVariable
}
```